# How can I generate a random number each time a variable is called?

Tags: c++

I'm making a very simple "Math tutor" program where I need to display a menu with 4 options: addition, subtraction, multiplication and exit. The program should loop until I choose to exit.

Everything so far seems to be working, but I can't figure out how to make a new random number every time the program is looped.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int addFirstNum,
    addSecondNum,
    subFirstNum,
    subSecondNum,
    multFirstNum,
    multSecondNum,
    operNum,
    num;
    bool temBool = true; //Temporary boolean used in the while loop
    unsigned seed; // Random generator seed

    // Use the time function to get a "seed" value for srand
    seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    //Random generated operands
    addFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    addSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    subFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    subSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    multFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    multSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;


    while (temBool) //Start of the loop
    {
        // Menu of Math Tutor
        cout << "Math Tutor - Main Menu";
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "1. Adittion\n";
        cout << "2. Subtraction\n";
        cout << "3. Multiplication\n";
        cout << "4. Exit Program\n";
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Choose your operation to practice (1-4) ";
        cin >> operNum;
        cout << endl << endl;

        // Switch for the menu's options
        switch (operNum)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Working with addition\n";
                cout << setw(3) << addFirstNum << "\n"
                << "+" << addSecondNum << "\n"
                << "---\n";
                cout << "Your answer: ";
                cin  >> num;
                if(num == addFirstNum + addSecondNum)
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << addFirstNum + addSecondNum << " Congratulations!\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << addFirstNum + addSecondNum << " Sorry!\n";
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Working with subtraction\n";
                cout << setw(3) << subSecondNum << "\n"
                << "-" << multFirstNum << "\n"
                << "---\n";
                cout << "Your answer: ";
                cin  >> num;
                if(num == subSecondNum - multFirstNum)
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << subSecondNum - multFirstNum << " Congratulations!\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << subSecondNum + multFirstNum << " Sorry!\n";
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Working with multiplication\n";
                cout << setw(3) << multFirstNum << "\n"
                << "*" << multSecondNum << "\n"
                << "---\n";
                cout << "Your answer: ";
                cin  >> num;
                if(num == multFirstNum * multSecondNum)
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << multFirstNum * multSecondNum << " Congratulations!\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Correct answer: "
                    << multFirstNum + multSecondNum << " Sorry!\n";
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Thank you for using Math Tutor.\n";
                temBool =  false;

                break;
            default:  cout << "Incorrect menu seletion. Please choose between 1 and 4.\n"; 
                return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

move the random value generator lines inside the loop:

```
seed = time(0);
srand(seed);    //setting the seed should only be done outside the loop (as per original code)

while (temBool) //Start of the loop
{

    //Random generated operands
    addFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    addSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    subFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    subSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    multFirstNum = rand() % 40 + 10;
    multSecondNum = rand() % 40 + 10;

    //...
}
```

Now every time it loops, the numbers will have a new value.

edit: Answer now shows `srand(seed)` explicitly outside the loop in case that was your problem was moving that code into the loop.
Also, like [whozcraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) said, you only need two random numbers each time as you are only using two of the numbers you are generating each time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This seemed obvious but I tried compiling it this way and I'm still not getting new numbers.

Comment: I took the beginning of your code and put the random number generation into the loop and made it loop 5 times.  Check it out: http://ideone.com/KEW6cf

Comment: Thank you that looks like it will work, but I'm still having issues incorporating it into my code so that it will give me new numbers each time. For example I choose 1 (addition) and I do it right after the congratulating message I get the menu once again, if I choose 1 again I will get the same numbers instead of a fresh set of random numbers. I know I'm missing something small here but I can't see it. Thank you

Comment: @RufioLJ it should ideally look [something like this](http://pastebin.com/TnwaXfZZ). (I removed the rampant repetitive numbers; all you need are two per-iteration).

Comment: @RufioLJ You didn't happen to also move `srand(seed);` inside the loop? That would give the same "random" sequence every time.

Comment: Your full program with my change from my answer: http://ideone.com/G6FDb7  output is different each time...

Comment: You are right thank you @Baldrickk I was mistakenly doing what molbdnilo said. Now it works as wanted. I should have figured it out this long ago! Thank you again. WhozCraig your code also seems to work quite well, I will study it. It seems to be a bit more advanced than what I'm currently learning, but eventually I will get there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition answer to Baldrick, when you seed with time(0) and then just do a while loop, without any stops or asking user what to do next( exit/continue ), the values will be the same you seed with the same value of time( time value didn't change because the while loop processed the program quickly ).Maybe it's not the issue here, but it's good to know :)

Comment: It seems to be an issue because I'm not getting new values while looping. Only when I run the program again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This answer plust Baldrickk's are guiding me into the solution. This information is actually what I need to work on.

Comment: As long as the seed isn't in the loop then the output from `rand()` will be different. the lines `seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);` should remain outside the loop.  Editing my answer to make that more explicit.